# p-adic Lie groups v.s. real Lie groups in philosophies

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, topological-groups, algebraic-groups, geometric-group-theory

What makes $p$-adic Lie groups interesting objects to study? I am not familiar with the representation theory or the number theory side of things, so I'd like to frame my question within the contexts of structural theories of topological groups and group action.

I know many theorems holds for Lie groups over local fields in general. For example, the superrigidity and arithmeticity theorems of Margulis, or the structural theorem of Nevo-Zimmer. However, it seems like many of the theorems are proven for real Lie groups first then generalized to the settings of p-adic Lie groups.  I am looking for interesting structural theories unique to p-adic Lie groups that is not true on real Lie groups, or theories on real Lie groups that completely fails with no analogs expected in the case of p-adic Lie groups.

I know p-adic Lie groups are are totally disconnected. How does this topology come into play?

Comment: In ${\rm SL}_n(\mathbf R)$, all maximal compact subgroups are conjugate (one such subgroup is ${\rm SO}_n(\mathbf  R)$), but in ${\rm SL}_n(\mathbf  Q_p)$, there are $n$ conjugacy classes of maximal compact subgroups.

Comment: To amplify what @KCd has said, there is am immensely deep, and rich theory of the compact subgroups of $p$-adic groups which goes under the moniker of *Bruhat--Tits theory*. This is interesting enough to sustain itself on its own, independent of its important (and substantial) ties to number theory.

That said, I would like to push back against the phrasing of the question a bit. While such beautiful innate reasons to study the topic of $p$-adic groups exist, it really is the connection to other fields that make their study so compelling.

Comment: (cont'd) To wit, "I know p-adic Lie groups are are totally disconnected. How does this topology come into play?" This question could be answered in its own right, but let just point out something of pivotal importance in modern number theory/arithmetic geometry which is directly tied to this question. You know what another example of a totally disconnected group is? The *Galois group of a field* (or, more generally, the etale fundamental group of a scheme). Such objects are too wild to be considered purely as abstract groups, and their topology plays a defining role in their study.

Comment: (cont'd) Consequently, the powerful theory of representation theory is brought to bear in a topological format: the study of continuous representations. But, as Galois groups are totally disconnected, one can show that Lie groups (which have the 'no small subgroups property') do not admit interesting representations from such objects. Instead, you need versions of Lie groups which admit more similar topologies. In comes $p$-adic Lie groups. In fact, a huge portion of modern number theory comes from studying representations of such Galois/fundamental groups into such $p$-adic Lie groups.